# How to read a date value with it's default format with excel input in Pentaho?

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

If I have a row with date values in it like '03-12-2020', it is converting it to another format after excel input like '2020/03/12' when I change its data type to String(default in the file is a date).
How to get the data in its default format (format is not static its dynamic may be 'yyyy-mm-dd' or 'mm-dd-yyyy' or 'mm/dd/yyyy')  like '03-12-2020' .

Comment: is date format different in same excel sheet like 1 row having different format and other having different. or is it different in different sheets.

Comment: I am not able to understand the problem clearly, based on column value, excel input step automatically fetches data-type for all the columns, you question is how to change to specific format, you can use select values step after excel input and modify data-type using meta-data properties for particular column.

Comment: @NK0709 The same sheet has different formats and data types. Few of the values are in a string and few are in date(Custom). In the excel input, I am changing it to string in the type but after that, all the values are changing to a default format. But I want them in the original format what is in the file only changing the type date to string.

Comment: @HelpingHand.. I don't want to change the formats what it is in the excel file but after the excel input step (I am putting the type as a string in the input) it is converting the formats into a default format if the values are of date(custom) in the excel sheet. How to convert that date to string keeping the original format in the excel sheet?

Comment: Ideally you should treat different formats as different sheets and convert the stream as part of ETL .. like excel1 has date format and excel2 has string format. Load them as seperate inputs and convert the same using select values and pass them as single stream going forward. Let me know if it sounds good or we can discuss further

Comment: @NK0709 i don't know which cells have a string format and which one have a date format in a particular column.